# Three.js pointer lock first person controls orbiting instead

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm not getting why my controls make the camera orbit around a certain point rather than do something similar to an FPS game.

I've been comparing my code to an [official example from three.js](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html) documentation and wish to achieve the same effect but i've hit a wall at some point and can't seem to find a mistake.

My miserable attempt can be viewed [here](http://bonewinged.tk/webGL/3DWorld.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either replace the line

```
camera.position.z = 100;
```

with

```
controls.getObject().position.z = 100;
```

or set the camera position before you apply it to the controls, like this:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, aspect, 0.1, 1000); //fov, aspect, near, far.
camera.position.z = 100;
var controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera);
```

Comment: The line should be `controls.getObject().position.z = 100;` but thank you so much!